# Save data within a TextView

Tags: java, android

I'm new to Android programming. I created an APP in which I added the videos to the prize, these videos give me a prize in coins, this coin prize is displayed in a `TextView` in percentage.

the problem is that when I leave the APP and return or turn it APP screen the `TextView` percentage counter will reset to zero and then the work of each user is deleted.
I need to find a method that I can not write, to save the credits earned up to 100% so the credits must remain until the end without anything to delete them, I tried the `onSaveInstanceState` outstate method and it does not work.

Below is the App code I wrote.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements RewardedVideoAdListener {

    private AdView mAdView;
    private WebView mywebview;
    private InterstitialAd mInterstitialAd;
    private FirebaseAnalytics mFirebaseAnalytics;
    private RewardedVideoAd mRewardedVideoAd;
    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getName();
    public double Coins;

    RelativeLayout Home;
    RelativeLayout PgCoins;
    Button btn1, btn2;
    ImageButton Backbtn;
    TextView mCoinscounter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        MobileAds.initialize(this, "");

        //counter CRD
        mCoinscounter = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Textcoins);

        // WEbView
        WebView mywebview = findViewById(R.id.mywebview);
        WebSettings webSettings = mywebview.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        mywebview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
        mywebview.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        mywebview.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
        mywebview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        mywebview.loadUrl("url");

        Home = findViewById(R.id.home);
        PgCoins = findViewById(R.id.pagecoins);

        btn1 = findViewById(R.id.btn1);
        btn2 = findViewById(R.id.btn2);
        Backbtn = findViewById(R.id.backbtn);

        Home.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        PgCoins.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        findViewById(R.id.btn2).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (mRewardedVideoAd.isLoaded()) {
                    mRewardedVideoAd.show();
                }
            }
        });

        mRewardedVideoAd = MobileAds.getRewardedVideoAdInstance(this);
        mRewardedVideoAd.setRewardedVideoAdListener(this);

        // ADMob Top
        mAdView = findViewById(R.id.adViewTop);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().setRequestAgent("android_studio:ad_template").build();
        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);

        // ADMob Bot
        mAdView = findViewById(R.id.adViewBot);
        AdRequest adRequest1 = new AdRequest.Builder().setRequestAgent("android_studio:ad_template").build();
        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest1);

        // ADMob Top Coins
        mAdView = findViewById(R.id.adViewTopcoins);
        AdRequest adRequest2 = new AdRequest.Builder().setRequestAgent("android_studio:ad_template").build();
        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest2);

        // ADMob Bot Coins
        mAdView = findViewById(R.id.adViewBotcoins);
        AdRequest adRequest3 = new AdRequest.Builder().setRequestAgent("android_studio:ad_template").build();
        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest3);

        //ADMob Interstitial
        prepareAd();
        ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
        scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
                            mInterstitialAd.show();
                        } else {
                            Log.d("TAG", "Interstitial not loaded");
                        }

                        prepareAd();
                    }
                });

            }
        }, 60, 60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        // Obtain the FirebaseAnalytics instance.
        mFirebaseAnalytics = FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(this);

        //ADMob Video
        loadRewardedVideoAd();

    }
    public void displayCrd (double amount){
            mCoinscounter.setText(String.format("%.2f", amount));
    }

    private void loadRewardedVideoAd() {
        mRewardedVideoAd.loadAd("ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/5224354917",
                new AdRequest.Builder().build());
    }

    //ADMob Interstitial
    public void prepareAd(){
        mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
        mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712");
        mInterstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
    }

    //Screen Change Page
    boolean Change = true;

    public void change(View view)
    {
        if (Change){
            Home.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            PgCoins.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            Change = false;
        }else{
            Home.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            PgCoins.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            Change = true;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRewardedVideoAdLoaded() {
        Log.d(TAG, "Video Caricato");
    }

    @Override
    public void onRewardedVideoAdOpened() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onRewardedVideoStarted() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onRewardedVideoAdClosed() {
        loadRewardedVideoAd();
    }

    @Override
    public void onRewarded(RewardItem rewardItem) {
        Toast.makeText(this, " Amount " + rewardItem.getType() + " : " + rewardItem.getAmount(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       Coins += rewardItem.getAmount();
       displayCrd(Coins/3600*100);
    }

    @Override
    public void onRewardedVideoAdLeftApplication() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onRewardedVideoAdFailedToLoad(int i) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Caricamento Fallito");
    }

    @Override
    public void onRewardedVideoCompleted() {
        loadRewardedVideoAd();
    }
}
```

Comment: save in shared preferences!

Comment: When you say "leave the app" do yo u kill it or make it go to background..??

Comment: yes when I close the app or go out of the app or due to an abnormal stop. In any case, I have to save the credits earned by the user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must have to use `SharedPreferences`

in that you can store your desired value and also retrieve it.

using this you can store value in prefereces

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
 editor.putInt("scrore", 10);
 editor.putString("userName", "xyz");
 editor.apply();
```

using this you can retrieve value from preferences

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE); 
String userName = prefs.getString("userName", null);
if (userName != null) {
  int scrore = prefs.getInt("scrore", 0);//0 is the default value.
}
```

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences

Comment: Thanks for the reply

Answer (score 0):

You can use shared preferences. It's basically you can save data with as key value. For more information visit to https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences

Write to Shared Preferences with Kotlin

```
val sharedPref = activity?.getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE) ?: return
with (sharedPref.edit()) {
    putInt(getString(R.string.saved_high_score_key), newHighScore)
    commit()
}
```

Read from Shared Preferences with Kotlin

```
val sharedPref = activity?.getSharedPreferences(
        getString(R.string.preference_file_key), Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
```

You have to do, save data onDestory and read data onCreate.

Comment: Thanks for the reply

Answer (score 0):

You can use ViewModel instead of onSaveInstanceState. It's new component by Android and its aware of activity lifecycle.

Read in brief here

https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel

And if you want to store data permanently then you should go for a mobile database.
You can use Realm DB to store your details and its pretty easy one.

You can find Realm example here

https://medium.com/@Zhuinden/why-realm-is-a-great-persistence-solution-for-beginners-in-android-development-6d69698efaad

Comment: Thanks for the reply

Comment: I will try to use this method, which I have never used until now, but I will try to learn it also because it is more useful for what I have to do thanks

Comment: also because I should save other data about the user in addition to the credits